# Disruptor EventReleaser.release() method

Tags: disruptor-pattern

Disruptor `EventReleaser.release()` method in Disruptor 3.3.6 com.lmax.disruptor.WorkProcessor.

I can't understand the method `sequence.set(Long.MAX_VALUE)`. Can anyone explain in detail what is the purpose of this method?

Answer (score 1):

I found [an anwser](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lmax-disruptor/kCRoPpBp1m8) in disruptor's google group.

It match to my test, when you don't use EventReleaser, ringbuffer will be exhausted, so the producers stuck at the next() method.